# Using kik's API with ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, http-authentication, httparty, kik

Ok so Im learning ruby and wanted to create a bot for kik https://dev.kik.com, I just don't understand whats wrong.

**Here is the Code**

```
require 'HTTParty'
require 'base64'
require 'json'

bot_name = #bot_name
api_key = #api_key
message = Message.new(self)

HTTParty.post('https://api.kik.com/v1/config',
headers: {
  'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
  'Authorization' => "#{bot_name}:#{api_key}",
},
 body: {
   "manuallySendReadReceipts" => false,
   "receiveReadReceipts" => true,
   "receiveDeliveryReceipts" => true,
   "receiveIsTyping" => true,
   message: [
   {
    body: message,
    to: user_name,
    type: 'text',
    chatId: chat_id
   }
  ],
  debug_output: $stdout
 }
)
```

**Here is the Error:**

```
kikBot.rb:7:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Message (NameError)
```

Most of this code was create from referencing this [gem](https://github.com/muaad/kik/blob/master/lib/kik.rb)

Is there a way to test this locally and have it print something out saying "the connection was successful" or something.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says. `uninitialized constant Massage`, whereas the line with the error tells us that the model ins named `Message`.

Seems like you have a typo somewhere in your code base. Search your code base for `Massage` and replace it with `Message`.